# How to loop until both columns have an empty cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Below code should fill column AJ with the =TODAY() formula, until it hits a empty cell in column B.

Works when there are empty cells in AJ (in comparison to B), but when AJ is filled it keeps looping, and stamps in dates in unneccesary rows in AJ (after B is empty).

My thought was to build an exemption that checks beforehand if the last Row of AJ and B are both empty, if this is true, then skip the loop, but haven't been able to get something off the ground.

```
Sub DateStomper()

Do
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("xxx").Select
    Range("AJ2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
Loop Until Range("AJ2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: Try to imagine that you reach your last cell on column B. Your code is adding `"TODAY()"` before it checks, so when you check if both are empty, column AJ will have today value. Use a For.. Next loop better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach. You can enter the formula without a loop, and using `xldown` is dubious in case you have nothing else in B.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long

On Error Resume Next 'in case there are no blanks
r = Range("B2", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)(1).Row
On Error GoTo 0

If r > 0 Then
    Range("AJ2:AJ" & r - 1).Formula = "=TODAY()"
Else
    MsgBox "No blanks in B"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub DateStomper()
Dim i as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i=2 to Range("B2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Range("AJ" & i).Formula = "=TODAY()"
Next i

End Sub
```

Just check if the formula is applied in the correct position. It is not clear for me if you need to apply in AJ2 -> AJ`Last Item + 1`.

Hope it helps